# Runtime Error 1004 when running Macro in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, excel-2016

I am getting this error when trying to run a macro in Excel 2016 that was written in Excel 2010...

> Runtime Error 1004:  Autofilter method of Range class failed.

Here is the debug code...

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:E") .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria:="<=0",
   Operator:=x1And
```

Is there any discrepancy between Excel 2010 and Excel 2016 that would cause this macro to fail when it worked perfectly in 2010?

I've gone through the trusted section in Excel and allowed everything I can think of so I believe it's an issue in the code itself that Excel 2016 doesn't like.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note - `xlAnd` - the letter `l` as in `Lima`, not the number `1`. Also, should be `Criteria1`.

Comment: Without a second criteria, (e.g. `Criteria2`), `Operator:=xLAnd` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you for the info.  Unfortunately the recommended changes did not solve the issue.  The error is still occurring.